# Display SQL Server image data type in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

How can I display the image data type (from SQL Server) in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question, but I have always found it best to place the location (path) of the file on your server in a database field (a string data type i.e. "varchar", "text", etc...), and use that to display the image on the web page via an  element.

Storing images in a database can be very cumbersome which is why I don't do it.

Hope this helps.